# How can i render a REACT component and get rid of the one that was running?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

this is my first post here.
I am new at REACT, and trying to develop a web interface for a database.
I have multiple files/components for the different elements (side menu, top menu, main content etc..)
I have this Home function which renders all of them correctly

```
function Home(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const projet = props.showProjet;
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <TopMenu />
            <SideMenu />
            <MainContent />
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}
```

But when i want to change the content of MainContent ( which are tables from a database) i always have the new one, and somewhere on the right of the webpage i have the one that was rendered at the beginning. How can i render the new one instead of the old one ?
For now i am rendering the new one through Link, Router and Switch in the TopMenu.
Thanks in advance !
Edit:
Here is the code with the Router part:

> 

```
         <Router>
            <AppBar position='fixed' className={classes.appBar}>
                <Toolbar>

                    <MenuItem >
                        <Typography variant='h6' className={classes.title}  >
                            <Link to="/table1">&lt;Table 1&gt;</Link>
                        </Typography>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem >
                        <Typography variant='h6' className={classes.title} >
                            <Link to="/table2">&lt;Table2&gt;</Link>

                        </Typography>
                    </MenuItem>
                    
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/table1">
                    <AppTableCarte />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/table2">
                    <AppTableType />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
```

I first render AppTableCarte from main content, but then render the other ones from TopMenu

Comment: Hi Antoine welcome to stackoverflow. can you show us your other components where you have Link, Route, Router components?

Comment: show us your MainContent component

Comment: how do you trigger the rendering of new contents?

Comment: I found another way, calling the first component through a router too, didn't know about the "exact" parameter so it was not showing the others if i had path="/"

Comment: Move the <Switch> into the <MainContent>..